# Cannot import custom font icons on my react app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, icons

I have trouble in importing icons on my react app.
I imported font icons from my database in my index.html like this:

```
 <link href='https://website/static/fonts/icons.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and then add the icons to the component like this:

```
<span class="icon-0001"></span>
```

icons are saved as:

```
.icon-0001:before {
content: "\e900";
}
.icon-0002:before {
 content: "\e901";
}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, I had to move the link to the `index.js` and that solved the problem.